# How to add Font with inner color and outer color

Tags: ios, swift, text, fonts, uicolor

I am working on photo editing App which is in ios swift 4 and i want to give functionality as followed

[image]

as in image I want to give inner color and outer color for Text.but i didn't have any idea about it. how can i acheive it is there any library of function

I have tried Some property of font as i had used shadow color and background color but it does not meet my requirement.
please help!

Comment: Are you asking us to create an online photoshop app for you or am i just missreading ?

Comment: @xoxel I am creating app in ios swfit 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of functionality with an [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring):

```
NSAttributedString(string: "Testing", attributes: [
.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.980392158, green: 0.5607843399, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
.strokeColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.03990633413, green: 0.1469032466, blue: 0.7415332794, alpha: 1),
.strokeWidth: -3,
.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)])
```

This results in a string that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it works, Thanks :)